# Problems with grunt

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser, gruntjs

I have some problems with grunt because it seems to do more things than I want it to do. I have two folders with two local grunts in them, but when I launch it locally from one folder, it does also do what the "other" grunt, in the other folder, should do. I have an index.html file in each folder with different code, leading to different JavaScript (.js) files, but grunt executes both of them. (First the one in the other folder, and then the one in the folder from where I launch it.)

I am not publishing any code at the moment because I feel that the question should be relatively code-independent, but if anyone thinks it is necessary to answer the issue, I'll do.

Do you think the issue originates from the global grunt that I installed before the local grunts? (I.e. it searches for all the files and executes the instructions?)

Any hints, ideas, suggestions? Thank you.

EDIT: a better description of my file structure. On the Desktop I have two folders (projects) with two local grunts installed. In the first project, index.html is:

```
<html>
<head><title>Testing grunt</title></head>
<body>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<h1>It works!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, app.js calls another .js file that fires up an alert message.

This works ok as a test. But in the second project (folder), this being in the Desktop too, index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cloud clicker game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello!!!</h1>
<div id="game"></div>
<script src="scripts/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Leading to a different app.js file that is a little sample game that I did using the phaser.js library.

The problem is that when I launch grunt from the "game" folder, both the "Hello!!!" and the alerts from the first folder show up, instead of the game that should be launched by the grunt that is in the game folder. No game starts, but this is another problem. First, I'd need to get rid of the alert (i.e. the "other" index.html being launched)

Hope this helps in better understanding the problem / situation.

EDIT: Here is my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    browserify: {
        main: {
          options: {
            browserifyOptions: {
              debug: true
            },
            transform: [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
          },
          src: 'src/app.js',
          dest: 'scripts/app.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
      files: [ 'src/**/*.js' ],
      tasks: ['browserify'],
      options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
    },
    connect: {
      target:{
            options: {
                port: 9001
            }
        }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'connect', 'watch']);

};
```

EDIT: Output of grunt --verbose

```
grunt --verbose Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-connect" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/package.json...OK
Loading "connect.js" tasks...OK
+ connect

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-browserify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-browserify/package.json...OK
Parsing /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-browserify/package.json...OK
Loading "browserify.js" tasks...OK
+ browserify
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "connect" task

Running "connect:target" (connect) task
Verifying property connect.target exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: protocol="http", port=9001, hostname="0.0.0.0", base=".", directory=null, keepalive=false, debug=false, livereload=false, open=false, useAvailablePort=false, onCreateServer=null, middleware=null
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/tasks/certs/server.key...OK
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/tasks/certs/server.crt...OK
Reading /home/alessandro/Desktop/Cloud_Clicker_Game/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/tasks/certs/ca.crt...OK
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9001

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Watching src/app.js for changes.
```

Comment: Please include a more concrete description of your file structure. And what do you mean by "global" grunt and "other" grunt? Are you talking about gruntfile.js?

Comment: To answer partially your comment, it is my understanding that grunt may be installed globally on a system, with npm install -g grunt-cli, and locally (I mean in a project), with npm install grunt. When I launch the command "grunt" within a project (i.e. in a folder) I am supposed to make the "local" grunt work.

Comment: I just added a better description of my file structure in the question.

Comment: OK, I think you have a misunderstanding of how grunt works. It doesn't really matter which grunt executable you run. All that really matters is which gruntfile.js you are invoking. In general, when you run `grunt` in a location (using any grunt executable), grunt will look for a gruntfile.js in the current directory, and then walk up the filesystem until it finds one. grunt will then use that file to invoke tasks.

Comment: Understood. As it turns out, the two gruntfile.js files are identical, because they should refer to two different app.js files, each one being in the 'src' folder of each project, and compile them in the 'scripts' folder of each project. But when I see the compiled app.js file in the game project, the src/app.js file of the test project is being compiled. I could of course delete the test project but that would be an harsh solution because I want to maintain more projects on the same system with different gruntfile.js.

Comment: I renamed gruntfile.js in the test project and reinstalled grunt in the game project with npm install grunt and npm install. It turns out that now it does only the "html" part of index.html, i.e. making the "Hello!!!" appear, but it doesn't work on the 'src/app.js' file (no 'scripts/app.js' file is being created).

Comment: So it seems that grunt is not writing the 'scripts/app.js' file in the game project, as requested in the gruntfile.js, that's why previously it was searching for the 'scripts/app' file that was in the other folder, and executing it (as strange as it may seem).

Comment: Something doesn't seem to be configured properly. Try running `grunt --verbose` and update your question with the output.

Comment: Done. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are never actually running the `browserify` task. When you run `grunt` on the command line without specifying a specific task, then it runs the `default` task, which in this case only runs `connect` and `watch`.

There are two ways to fix:

1. simply invoke `grunt browserify` on the command line
2. change the default task to: `['browserify', 'connect', 'watch']`

Comment: That pretty much answers my question, thank you very much.